# How does the "syscall" instruction works on mips assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips

lets have for example this code:

```
.data
    msg: .asciiz "Hello world!" #message to be shown


.text
    li $v0, 4 #instruction for string printing
    la $a0, msg #indication of where the string is
    syscall #make it print
```

"li" is gonna call the instruction to prepare a print, "la" is gonna make the variable msg go to the register "a0", i know syscall is supposed to print the message, but how exactly it does that? how does it know which register it must print? because i haven't indicated anywhere in the syscall which register to print (while in language c for example it would be something like printf("%s",msg)) but it knows it must print $a0 anyways and i don't know how and why.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, the `syscall` instruction merely transfers control of processor (the instruction execution stream) to the system/kernel exception handler.  That exception handler has software that does all the operations of each particular `syscall`, and then returns to the user code — it is this software that knows to look at `$v0` and `$a0`.  It's like a subroutine call but to the kernel code instead of user subroutines.  The hardware instruction basically "jump" over there, and then software does the rest.

More specifically, the `syscall` instruction invokes the exception mechanism.  It captures the PC of the executing user code, then changes to privilege mode, sets the cause of the exception, and changes the PC to 0x80000800, which starts running the kernel exception handler.

I say in theory, because using the simulators, they do similar but the `syscall` may be implemented as software that is directly within the simulator itself (instead of as a simulated exception handler); if implemented this way, the software also knows about each particular `syscall`, what registers have what parameters, and how to return to the user code after running the operation.

Comment: wait, so syscall will always print the $a0?

Comment: Neither the `syscall` instruction nor the exception handler know that your code just recently loaded `$v0` and `$a0` registers.  They "know" (i.e. they assume), by simple definition, to look at the values in those specific registers.  (They are not looking backwards in the instruction stream to see what instructions preceded.)

Comment: This: looking in agreed upon locations, is how parameter passing usually works.  There's no guessing where to find parameters; there's no looking to see what the code did prior to a call: it is agreement in advance, published and well-known, to find parameters in certain specific registers.  Because it is based on location (i.e. what register) the order they are "passed" doesn't matter, so we can set `$a0` first, then `$v0`, and it will still have the same effect in the `syscall`.

Comment: but what exactly syscall wants to print? i know syscall will always look at $v0 for the instruction of what it should do, but is there a definition of what it should always print? is there a register that syscall will always print?

Comment: http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html